# Having real trouble combining 2 JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling combining two JS into one… I try and try in the JSFiddle but can not really understand the console erros…

I am trying to have a background-color that changes combined with a changing background .svg in a div…

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 //Initializing
var i = 0;
var images = []; //array
var time = 3000; // time in millie seconds

//images

images[0] = "url(http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/verve/img/logo_1.svg)";
images[1] = "url(http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/verve/img/logo_2.svg)";
images[2] = "url(http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/verve/img/logo_3.svg)";
images[3] = "url(http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/verve/img/logo_4.svg)";
//function

function changeImage() {
var el = document.getElementById('header');
el.style.backgroundImage = images[i];
if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
} else {
    i = 0;
}
setTimeout('changeImage()', time);
}

window.onload = changeImage;


$(function setbackground() {
        window.setTimeout( "setbackground()", 2000);
var index = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
var ColorValue = "FA89CB";
if(index == 1)
ColorValue = "FAED96";
if(index == 2)
ColorValue = "D27DFA";
if(index == 3)
ColorValue = "6CFA64";
if(index == 4)
ColorValue = "8370FA";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "#" + ColorValue;

});



});
```

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gmck02ru/1/

does somebody have a clue – i guess I am not really understanding what I am doing here so far...
Help please!

Comment: There are no console errors, it works on my machine.

Comment: It says "ReferenceError: setbackground is not defined" – the background color should be changing and the Lettering too :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the syntax you've used to define the `setbackground()` function is incorrect. You've placed it inside a jQuery object. That function is also never called. You should define it as a standalone function and invoke it when the page loads.

In addition there's a few improvements you can make to the logic.

- Use `addEventListener()` over setting the `onclick` or other `onX` event properties.
- Declare the elements of the array at the same time as you define the array itself.
- Use an array to hold the background colours instead of hard-coding an `if` statement.
- Use the modulo operator when incrementing the counter to save having to write logic to reset to `0`
- If you want to repeatedly update the background colour, as you do for the images, place the `setTimeout()` call within the `setbackground()` function.
- Use `document.body` directly instead of getting it by tag name

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let i = 0;
  let images = [
    "url(http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/verve/img/logo_1.svg)",
    "url(http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/verve/img/logo_2.svg)",
    "url(http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/verve/img/logo_3.svg)",
    "url(http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/verve/img/logo_4.svg)"
  ];
  let backgroundColours = ['#FAED96', '#D27DFA', '#6CFA64', '#8370FA']

  function changeImage() {
    let el = document.getElementById('header');
    el.style.backgroundImage = images[i];
    i = ++i % (images.length - 1)
    setTimeout(changeImage, 3000);
  }
  changeImage();

  function setbackground() {
    let index = Math.round(Math.random() * 4);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColours[index];
    setTimeout(setbackground, 2000);
  }
  setbackground();
});
```

[**Working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4vpkrs37/1/) - see the demo in the fiddle as the images are on an insecure domain so cannot be called from SO.

Comment: …thank you so much! Yes the lettering changes now – but somehow the background-color only changes once at my machine?

Comment: Because you call `setTimeout()` outside of the function. To make it repeat infinitely either use `setInterval()`, or move the `setTimeout()` call inside the function - as you do for `updateImage()`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! It works! Ok I ll get into it to really understand it – thank you so much for helping!

Comment: No problem, glad to help